# Первая страница в Spring MVC

Tags: java, spring, mvc

Как сделать так чтобы какая та заданная страница сразу открывалась когда запускаешь Spring MVC проект в IntellijIdea?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Задать в дескрипторе развёртывания

```
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>/path/to/view</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
```

Или замапить какой-нибудь контроллер на корень контекста

```
@RequestMapping("/")
```